# BCP utility on linux: NativeError = 18456 Error = [unixODBC][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user

Tags: sql-server, odbc, bcp

Following BCP example (installed on CentOS7 via https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-setup-tools?view=sql-server-2017#a-idrhelainstall-tools-on-rhel-7 with the msodbcsql driver from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) for importing flatfile from linux to a MSSQL Server (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-migrate-bcp?view=sql-server-2017#import-data-from-the-source-data-file), getting error when trying to run basic command to write a flatfile from local machine (CentOS7) to a remote (Windows Server 2012) host DB.
The script being used for testing here looks like:

```sh
[me@mapr001 examples]$ cat simple-bcp-tsv2mssql.sh
#!/bin/bash

TO_SERVER_ODBCDS="-D -S 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server'"
TO_SERVER_IP="-S 172.17.9.29"
DB="DB_ML"
TABLE="bcp_test"
USER=""
PASSWORD=""
DATAFILE="./data/simple-rows.headless.tsv"

read -r -p "Enter username: " USER
read -r -s -p "Enter user password: " PASSWORD

echo -e "\nConnecting with BCP utility as $USER..."

/opt/mssql-tools/bin/bcp "$TABLE" in "$DATAFILE" \
        "$TO_SERVER_DNS" \
        -U "$USER" \
        -P "$PASSWORD" \
        -d "$DB" \
        -c \
        -t "'\t'"
```

and is throwing the (seemingly misleading) error

```
[me@mapr001 examples]$ ./simple-bcp-tsv2mssql.sh
Enter username: me
Enter user password:
Connecting with BCP utility as me...
/opt/mssql-tools/bin/bcp:  unknown option
usage: /opt/mssql-tools/bin/bcp {dbtable | query} {in | out | queryout | format} datafile
  [-m maxerrors]            [-f formatfile]          [-e errfile]
  ...
```

even though I appear to be following this usage format in the script. The results when running via commandline are what I think I **should really be focusing on**:

```
[me@mapr001 examples]$ bcp bcp_test in ./data/simple-rows.headless.tsv -D -S MyMSSQLServer -U me -P mypassword -d DB_ML -c -t '\t'

SQLState = 28000, NativeError = 18456
Error = [unixODBC][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'me'.
```

The /etc/odbc/odbc files on this machine look like

```
# Referencing some of the ODBC setup steps here: https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Connecting-to-SQL-Server-from-RHEL-6-or-Centos-7
# Prepare a temp file for defining the DSN to your database server
vi /home/user/odbcadd.txt

[MyMSSQLServer]
Driver      = ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
Description = My MS SQL Server
Trace       = No
Server      = 172.17.9.29

# register the SQL Server database DSN information in /etc/odbc.ini
sudo odbcinst -i -s -f /home/me/odbcadd.txt -l

[me@mapr001 examples]$ cat /etc/odbc.ini
[MyMSSQLServer]
Driver=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server    ------------
Description=My MS SQL Server                       |
Trace=No                                           |
Server=172.17.9.29                                 |
                                                   |
[MyMSSQLServer_ML]                                 |
Driver=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server               |
Description=My SQL Server (ML DB)                  |
Tracec=No                                          |
Server=172.17.9.29                                 |
Database=DB_ML                                     |
                                                   |
                                                   |
[me@mapr001 examples]$ cat /etc/odbcinst.ini       |
[PostgreSQL]                                       |
Description=ODBC for PostgreSQL                    |
Driver=/usr/lib/psqlodbcw.so                       |
Setup=/usr/lib/libodbcpsqlS.so                     |
Driver64=/usr/lib64/psqlodbcw.so                   |
Setup64=/usr/lib64/libodbcpsqlS.so                 |
FileUsage=1                                        |
                                                   |
[MySQL]                                            |
Description=ODBC for MySQL                         |
Driver=/usr/lib/libmyodbc5.so                      |
Setup=/usr/lib/libodbcmyS.so                       |
Driver64=/usr/lib64/libmyodbc5.so                  |
Setup64=/usr/lib64/libodbcmyS.so                   |
FileUsage=1                                        |
                                                   |
[ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]    <---------------- 
Description=Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
Driver=/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.2.so.0.1
UsageCount=1


[me@mapr001 ~]# odbcinst -q -d -n "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server"
[ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]
Description=Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
Driver=/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.2.so.0.1
UsageCount=1


[me@mapr001 ~]# odbcinst -j
unixODBC 2.3.1
DRIVERS............: /etc/odbcinst.ini
SYSTEM DATA SOURCES: /etc/odbc.ini
FILE DATA SOURCES..: /etc/ODBCDataSources
USER DATA SOURCES..: /etc/odbc.ini
SQLULEN Size.......: 8
SQLLEN Size........: 8
SQLSETPOSIROW Size.: 8
```

The problem appears to be related to how I've setup ODBC drivers and configs or with my credentials (which are `Active Directory` credentials that I use to login to the remote Windows machine hosting the SQL Server I'm trying to connect to here), but I have zero experience setting this kind of thing up and at this point am at a bit of a loss as to what to do (will continue researching and debugging). Any advice on how to further debug or fix the problem would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem appears to be that the `bcp` utility expects credentials for the SQL Server (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility?view=sql-server-2017#U and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility?view=sql-server-2017#T), **not the crednetials for the host machine that the SQL Server is running on**.

In my original post, was using the domain `Active Directory` creds. that I would normally use to login to the machine (which, again, is wrong (further supported here: https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/FindPost1565871.aspx)). Using a separate set of SQL Server credentials instead in the command solved my problem. (Still don't get why the script is throwing "unknown option" error, so if anyone has a guess, please leave a comment).

---

*UPDATE*: After some "binarysearch debugging" (https://www.codelord.net/2012/04/10/using-binary-search-for-debugging/), found that the problem was that the `field_term` option (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility?view=sql-server-2017#t) was formatted in a way that was causing some problems. Originally wrote the code in the script as `-t "'\t'"`. Changing this to `-t "\t"` (no inner single quotes) fixed the problem. Note that this was hard to immediately catch because when `echo`ing both versions of the command printed to the *console exactly the same*.